# The Comparison of Up-Votes Between Questions & Answers

Tags: discussion, questions, voting

I seem to see a pattern where Answers receive far more up-votes than the Questions they answer. I even see instances where an Answer has been selected while the Question remains at Zero votes.

So, my question is: if a question is worth answering isn't it also worthy of at least 1 up-vote?

Comment: "Worth" in what sense? To whom? Clearly, as you point out, not to the voting public today. Are you suggestion we impose or enforce through software or sanctions such a "balance"? Anyway, in your daily life, don't you value solutions over problems? After all, questions are infinite, (correct) answers finite.

Comment: Well, @Dan Bron, I wasn't suggesting *anything*. I was trying to initiate a discussion [*the tag*] which might elicit information from more experienced users (*such as yourself*) about the topic. I would imagine there is a correspondence between questions and answers. In my initial tour of the site I seem to recall coming across some good writing encouraging users to write and submit "good" questions because they generate "good" answers. Why do you have to jump to words like "impose," "enforce," and "sanction"? This is all brand new to me. I'm still trying to learn how to use a computer.

Comment: Don't stress out. I wasn't trying to condemn yourself or your question. I bear you no ill will. As you learn to use your computer, and in particular interact with strangers -- or even loved ones -- through the sole lens of text, you'll find it *very* (very!!) easy to misconstrue (and be misconstrued) the written word, and read into it intentions and emotions the auto did not and does not bear. I personally am no less guilty of this than anyone else. It's just a risk inherent in an information-constrained medium.

Comment: @Dan Bron, that's helpful, and I appreciate what you say. But, Dan, back to my question, it sounds like you might be able to provide some answers that would increase my understanding of site dynamics.

Comment: Sure. It's 1am for me, and I'm on a phone rather than computer, so I can't do it now, but tomorrow I'll try to post a formal answer to your question. It will be along the lines I laid out earlier: it's easier to judge the value of an answer than a question, and people's voting habits reflect that. That's the objective reality, but the subjective advice, which I think more important and much more valueable is: learn not to care. The "*gamification*" premise which underlies this and similar sites has motivational advantages, but also corresponding risks: beware of them.

Comment: Also, I suppose in a couple hours the Brits will wake up and come in, so you may have a high-quality and informative answer soon. Though they'll spell everything all wrong, of course.

Comment: @Dan Bron - you're *virtually* prescient (no pun). Another "user," only just now *schooled* me on site *gamesmanship* by voting down everyone's answer (including mine) but their own, which of course put them on top. But it's a cheap lesson (*2-points*, right?). Though I'm new to computers and even newer to this site, I'm not new to the human race. Still, it's a pity. Thanks for the attention and the advice.

Comment: Oh no, @Dan Bron, the British are coming ...

Comment: European user here, your question is not new. The same thing has been observed and commented before on Meta. In fact a popup does appear prompting  users to vote on questions, if they have only voted on answers. I don't remember the exact number, perhaps something like ten upvotes in a row for answers.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A - He started it, Mari-Lou. I was just playing along. Giving him enough rope, and all that rot. Anyway, rumor has it you're out of commission. Moreover, you're English is as native as it gets, but thanks for the tip. I looked at the questions that appeared as I labeled mine but didn't see a match - is there another approach. Come clean, where did you learn the English?

Comment: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4571/why-are-questions-answered-with-no-upvotes

Comment: Reading comments on an iPhone screen is ruining my eyesight, and my fat fingers slow down communication. I've never been a fan of texting. In answer to your query, I was born in the UK but left the shores of Dover when I was a young teenager 

Comment: Andrew Leach could you please confirm that a popup suggesting users to occasionally upvote questions appears? I'm sure it's somewhere on Meta but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @Mari I can confirm it.

Comment: You're a die-hard, @Dan Bron.

Comment: @Mari-Lou, thanks. I read the whole link. Interesting stuff, lots of different takes on the issue. Is it more effective to search for like questions by category tags? The reason I asked that other question (not meaning to pry) was because I thought you spoke perfect American.

Comment: "I'm still trying to learn how to use a computer." - a person after mine own heart! Little Eva, downvoting the answers of others is hardly common here. There is, however, a badge called *sportsmanship*, which is given to people who upvote good answers that compete with their own. That's a better pill to swallow. :-)

Comment: @medica - yeah, I get it, thanks. It's always a pleasure getting your *bings*. We all chase esteem but some methods are more productive in the long run, than others. here's a link: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221622/how-to-refer-to-the-upper-flat-part-of-a-cliff/221625#221625.